# iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I have an app where, in **Interface Builder**, I set up a `UIView` that has a text field near the bottom of the view.  When I run the app and try to enter text into that field, the keyboard slides up overtop of the field so I can't see what I'm typing until I hide the keyboard again.

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a good way to solve it without either making the parent view scrollable or moving the text field farther up the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

The usual solution is to slide the field (and everything above it) up with an animation, and then back down when you are done.  You may need to put the text field and some of the other items into another view and slide the view as a unit.  (I call these things "plates" as in "tectonic plates", but that's just me).  But here is the general idea if you don't need to get fancy.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: It is useful to cover all of screen as below:
    const int movementDistance = textField.frame.origin.y / 2; // tweak as needed

Comment: this does not work very well when user switches the keyboard from normal keyboard to an international keyboard, which has a different height.

Comment: I have to mention that "If your are writing an application for iOS 4 or later, you should use the block-based methods for animating your content instead." Referenced from : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW3

Comment: If you have multiple text fields and only want 1 to animate, add a tag in the xib file and have an if statement before the animate statements if(textField.tag == 1) [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];

Comment: This works perfectly (in terms of the animation values) for an iPhone 4S on iOS 6.1.3 (Retina 3.5" screen)

Comment: Still works perfectly with iOS 7.0.3, thanks for the simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Still works on iOS 7.1 (iPad). The offset doesn't stick after rotating though, so you'd have to set it again in the 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation' method.

Comment: Found this and it discusses the same issue https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

Answer (score 38):

This worked wonders for me [sliding uitextfields](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html)

In particular it has the benefit of calculating the slide animation distance depending on the position of the text field.

Comment: This is great. You don't have to pick some 'movement distance' constant for each text field -- it's calculated for you.

Comment: Best solution by far. Phenomenal mechanism!

Comment: Works great on the iPad too. I just updated PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 264 and LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 352. Great link. Thanks.

Comment: The above link just made my day! So simple to implement, works flawlessly so far!

Comment: Works great, just copy paste almost. Good explaination as well.

Comment: This is best the explanation out there about this topic. Other tutorials use Table Views, Scroll Views, etc. This actually works without getting into any other complexities, plain and simple. Thanks for sharing this source.

Answer (score 28):

[IQKeyboardManager](http://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) do this for you with **NO LINE OF CODE**, only need to drag and drop related source file to project. [IQKeyboardManager](http://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) also support **Device Orientation**, **Automatic UIToolbar Management**, **keyboardDistanceFromTextField** and much more than you think.

[image]

Here is the Control Flow Chart:
[image: Control Flow Chart]

**Step1:-** Added global notifications of `UITextField`, `UITextView`, and `UIKeyboard` in a singleton class. I called it [IQKeyboardManager](http://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).

**Step2:-** If found `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` or `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notifications, then try to get `topMostViewController` instance from the `UIWindow.rootViewController` hierarchy. In order to properly uncover `UITextField`/`UITextView` on it, `topMostViewController.view`'s frame needs to be adjusted.

**Step3:-** Calculated expected move distance of `topMostViewController.view` with respect to first responded `UITextField`/`UITextView`.

**Step4:-** Moved `topMostViewController.view.frame` up/down according to the expected move distance.

**Step5:-** If found `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification` or `UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification` notification, then again try to get `topMostViewController` instance from the `UIWindow.rootViewController` hierarchy.

**Step6:-** Calculated disturbed distance of `topMostViewController.view` which needs to be restored to it's original position.

**Step7:-** Restored `topMostViewController.view.frame` down according to the disturbed distance.

**Step8:-** Instantiated singleton [IQKeyboardManager](http://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) class instance on app load, so every `UITextField`/`UITextView` in the app will adjust automatically according to the expected move distance.

That's all

Comment: The accepted answer wasn't working for me. But this one does.

Comment: @ZaEeMZaFaR IQKeyboardManager is also optimised for iPad. Can you please open an issue on library github repo and upload a demo project demonstrating the issue with iPad?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will do that if issue persists, before you comment I was thinking that IQKeyboardManager is not for universal device.

Comment: By Investigating more, its working fine with iPad on simulator but not on actual iPad device. Working perfectly fine on iPhone as well (Device + Simulator). What could be the issue ?

Comment: As I previously said, you should raise an issue on github repo with demo project with your iOS and device version details, so we can look into the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was looking to post a POC where I found that 'split keyboard' was turned ON in iOS system preferences. And that was issue which stops the controller to listen keyboard notification. Worked like charm when I turned off the split keyboard.

Comment: The accepted answer work only when you set the delegate of every UITextField. This framework works in anyone UITextField, I think this is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 7):

I have face the same issue in `UITableView`  textField cells. I solve this issue by implementing following method to listen the keyboard notification.

Observer for the notifications here:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Handle those notification by using below function:

```
(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
(void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
```

Comment: The link is broken. Please consider including an independent solution in the future!

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Amagrammer answer, here is a sample class:

LoginViewController.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField    *emailTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField    *passwordTextField;
```

Notice we are implementing the "UITextFieldDelegate"

LoginViewController.m

```
@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize emailTextField=_emailTextField;
@synthesize passwordTextField=_passwordTextField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //Register to receive an update when the app goes into the backround
        //It will call our "appEnteredBackground method
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appEnteredBackground)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
//This is called when the app goes into the background.
//We must reset the responder because animations will not be saved
- (void)appEnteredBackground{
    [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, else it'll move more downward if one press Home button and come again into the app, causing it to ugly and buggy.

Answer (score 7):

How about the official solution: [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

> Adjusting your content typically involves temporarily resizing one or
>   more views and positioning them so that the text object remains
>   visible. The simplest way to manage text objects with the keyboard is
>   to embed them inside a UIScrollView object (or one of its subclasses
>   like UITableView). When the keyboard is displayed, all you have to do
>   is reset the content area of the scroll view and scroll the desired
>   text object into position. Thus, in response to a
>   UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, your handler method would do the
>   following:
>
> 1. Get the size of the keyboard.
> 2. Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard
>      height.
> 3. Scroll the target text field into view.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: This official solution is now wrapped in a control see here:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707094/1582217

Comment: Idea is good, but 'contentInset' property does not help here, coz contentInset will just provide you the padding effect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049782/260665

Comment: @Raj, That may be the case which I can look on IQKeyboardManager, but still no one open any issues on the official IQKeyboardManager github repository regarding the contentInset property issue, so I assume it's working.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out.
No hassle for you.

This solution is very neat. All you have to do is to add your textfields in a `UIScrollView` and change its class to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScollView`, if you are using storyboards. The scroll view is extended in such a way that it would detect when keyboard is visible and will move itself above keyboard at a reasonable distance. It is perfect solution because its independent of your `UIViewController`. Every necessary thing is done within the the above mentioned class. Thanks Michael Tyson et all.

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Comment: @NANNAV - Please provide comments when you make suggestions to modify an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a swift version of Amagrammer's answer.  Also, a variation using the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification event since I needed to know the keyboards size before moving the view out of the way.

```
var keyboardHeight:CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillChange:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    //keyboardWillChange (below) is used instead of textFieldDidBeginEditing because textFieldDidBeginEditing
    //is called before the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification necessary to determine the keyboard height.
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateTextField(false)
}

func animateTextField(textFieldUp:Bool) {
    let movementDistance:CGFloat = keyboardHeight
    let movementDuration = 0.3

    let movement:CGFloat = (textFieldUp ? -movementDistance : movementDistance)

    UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func keyboardWillChange(notification:NSNotification) {
    let keyboardRect:CGRect = ((notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey])?.CGRectValue)!
    keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.height
    animateTextField(true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There was a great walkthrough at [editing textfields without obscuring](http://acts-as-geek.blogspot.com/2009/11/editing-textfields-without-obscuring.html) (link dead now, here's a Wayback link: https://web.archive.org/web/20091123074029/http://acts-as-geek.blogspot.com/2009/11/editing-textfields-without-obscuring.html). It shows how to move an existing `UIView` onto a `UIScrollView`, and to scroll it automatically when the keyboard appears.

I've updated it a bit to calculate the correct height for the `UIScrollView` when there are controls (such as a `UITabBar`) below the `UIScrollBar`. See [post updating uiview](http://gargantuchet.blogspot.com/2009/12/i-came-across-post-updating-uiview-to.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Xcode5, iOS7:

Use the UITextfieldDelegate and animation blocks.

This is nearly all the code for the ViewController but I wanted to include the delegate code for those still somewhat unfamiliar with the delegate pattern (like me). I also included code to hide the keyboard when you tap away from the textview.

You can move the views(buttons, textfields, etc) as high as you'd like just make sure to put them back in place (+100 then later -100).

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *MyTextField;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.MyTextField.delegate = self;

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      NSLog(@"text began editing");

      CGPoint MyPoint = self.MyTextField.center;

      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                    animations:^{

                    self.MyTextField.center = CGPointMake(MyPoint.x, MyPoint.y - 100);
                                }];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     NSLog(@"text ENDED editing");

     CGPoint MyPoint = self.MyTextField.center;

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{

     self.MyTextField.center = CGPointMake(MyPoint.x, MyPoint.y + 100);
                             }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way would be to move your whole views position from (x,y) to (x,y-keybaardHeight) when the textfield is clicked and put it back when the keyboard is dismissed , might look a little odd as the view just comes up (maybe it wouldnt be bad if you animate it).

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect frame=self.view.frame;
    frame.origin=CGPointMake(x...//set point here
    self.view.frame=frame;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. If the user taps the first textfield it will get above the visible area.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop framework that I use in my projects. Supports automatic dismissal when you tap outside of a first responder or when you scroll.

[GTKeyboardHelper](https://github.com/mackross/GTKeyboardHelper)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Amagrammer's solution, if you are using cocos2d in portrait mode change this line:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
```

to this:

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.frame = CGRectOffset([CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.frame, movement, 0);
```

If you are using cocos2d in landscape mode, make the above change and switch the `up` values in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found GTKeyboardHelper to be an easy way out.

After drag and drop the framework in your project, include the header file.
Download and open the example project, then drag the "Keyboard Helper" object from the objects section in the xib to the objects section in your project's interface builder.

Drag and drop all your views to be children of the "Keyboard Helper".

Answer (score 0):

Just slide the view up and down as needed :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = nil;
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void) animateTextField:(UITextField*) textField up:(BOOL)up {
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:movementDuration animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    }];
}
```

Don't forget to set `self` as a `UITextFieldDelegate` and as the actual textField `delegate`.

(Thanks to Ammagrammer, this is just a shorter answer using blocks for animations)

Answer (score 0):

I have something else if you want. The point here is that you want to set the center your UIView on the text field you are editing.

Before that, you have to save your **INITIAL_CENTER**, as a **CGPoint**, from self.view.center and your **INITIAL_VIEW** as a **CGRect** from self.view.frame in a const property.

You can create a method like this :

```
- (void) centerOn: (CGRect) fieldFrame {

    // Set up the center by taking the original view center
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(INITIAL_CENTER.x,
                             INITIAL_CENTER.y - ((fieldFrame.origin.y + fieldFrame.size.height/2) - INITIAL_CENTER.y));


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"centerViewOnField" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];

    if (CGRectEqualToRect(fieldFrame,INITIAL_VIEW)) {
        self.view.frame = INITIAL_VIEW;
        [self.view setCenter:INITIAL_CENTER];
    } else {
        [self.view setCenter:center];
    }


    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then, on your **UITextFieldDelegate**, you have to call **centerOn:(CGRect)** in following methods :

**textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)** with, as a parameter, the frame of the text field you want to center on.

And you have to call it in your event handler, where you close your keyboard,

**textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)** can be one of the ways to do it, putting the INITIAL_VIEW as a parameter of **centerOn:(CGRect)**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe on newer versions of iOS (6.1+, possibly even earlier), the underlying view, at least for UITableView, auto-shrinks when the keyboard pops up. So you only need to make the text field visible in that view. In `init`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

then:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Scroll the text field into view so it's not under the keyboard.
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView convertRect:inputView.bounds fromView:inputView];
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ZulwiyozaPutra/Shift-Keyboard-Example I hope this solution helped. They are all Swift 3 written.

```html
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Shift Keyboard Example
//
//  Created by Zulwiyoza Putra on 11/23/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Zulwiyoza Putra. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    
    //connecting textfield from storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.textField.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }
    
    //Hide keyboard after finished editing
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    //Setup view before keyboard appeared
    func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification:Notification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }
    
    //Setup view before keyboard disappeared
    func keyboardWillDisappear(_ notification: Notification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
    
    //Getting keyboard height
    func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }
    
    //Subscribing to notifications to execute functions
    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
    
    //Unsubscribing from notifications
    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
    
}
```