# iOS move ToolBar with keyboard in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, keyboard, toolbar

I'm going crazy. I'll try to move the ToolBar with its textfield when the key board is appearing. With the following code the view is really moving but the ToolBar stays and gets hidden by the keyboard:

```
- (void) liftMainViewWhenKeybordAppears:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
CGRect keyboardFrame;
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I'm a beginner so please don't beat me up but I don't know the missing link to move and show the ToolBar with its textfield.

The toolbar and the textfield is created in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.view does not contain the toolbar, you have to move the toolbar separately ...

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the toolbar is part of the view. How can I move the ToolBar which is created in the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: When you create the toolbar in code, save it as property. Then you can adjust it anywhere ...

Comment: Alright, but the ToolBar comes with the Navigation Controller and is shown with `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];`. How can I save it as property? Do I need to create and initialize an custom ToolBar for that?

Comment: Adjust the size of self.navigationController.view.frame

Comment: Oh, something happens. Now the whole screen is black. I might need to adapt the sizes again.

Comment: I'm close... Give me a little bit.

Comment: Allright, took me a while but I figured out that I had to move the ToolBar: `[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake...`. Thanks for you hint.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that the ToolBar itself has to move with the keyboard:
This prevents it from get hidden by the appearing keyboard:

[image]

When using a ToolBar in a NavigationController the following code should do the trick:

```
- (void) liftMainViewWhenKeybordAppears:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
CGRect keyboardFrame;

[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];    

[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.size.height +self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height,
                                                       self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width,
                                                       self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

All the other necessary code is pretty well described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951826/move-up-uitoolbar).