# UIScrollview does not scroll all the way through

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll

So I have a scrollview that I dropped into my view (in the nib file), hence nothing has been done programmatically yet. I have then placed 9 buttons spaced out in this scrollview. Now the scrollview works perfectly, it scrolls smoothly and everything, however it does not scroll all the way down to the 9th button. It makes it as far as the 7th button, which I assume is the screen size, and scrolls now further. Do I have to do anything programmatically to fix this or can I just edit the nib file?

Comment: InViewDidLoad : Just Place this [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourScrollView.bounds.size.width,yourScrollView.bounds.size.height + 100)]; '100' is just a sample. You need to put exactly by calculation

Comment: Am I supposed to substitute anything in the place of bounds size and width?

Comment: no need.. Just place that. it will work.. But, Make sure you are setting the height perfectly...

Comment: Well when I do that I get an error saying that xcode expects a ")" at the period between bounds and size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: alright, it doesn't give that error anymore, however this does not change the situation at all, as I'm having the same problem.

Comment: change your height friend... just put some static value for the time being..like 560. then check. Just do increasing the height. and please let me know what you did ?

Comment: that's what I did. I tried increasing values from 100 to 800. The code doesn't seem to affect the scrollview whatsoever though.

Comment: Did You set the scrollview Delegate in xib file

Comment: Yes, I connected it to the file owner

Comment: Can you please take a screen shot of your UIView and scrollView pleasae?

Comment: I can't really since it's someone else's project that I am working on. The scrollview is inside the UIview, and the buttons inside the scrollview.

Comment: Is it for iphone for ipad...

Comment: Have you connected the ScrollView to an IBOutlet in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView won't scroll!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272854/uiscrollview-wont-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure You have declared object for scrollview and connected properly and setDelegate too in xib.

and then

In `ViewDidLoad` please place this code..

```
int width = 320; (if iphone)

int height = 440; (if iphone)

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)];
```

Please make sure your height and width according to your calculation.