# UIScrollView AutoLayout Vertical Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

**I want to get the AutoLayout working with the `UIScrollView` and am having a little trouble with it. Here is what I did:**

1. Add a `UIScrollView` inside the Main View with frame: [top: 0, left: 0, width: 320, height: 568]
2. Add `UIView` "ContentView" inside the `UIScrollView` with frame and bgcolor black: [top: 0, left: 0, width: 320, height: 568]
3. Setup `UIScrollView` constraints: [top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0]
4. Setup "ContentView" constraints: [top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0]
5. Align the items inside the "ContentView"
6. Set Main View bgcolor to gray (to see what's going on)

**Here is a screenshot of the problem:**

[image: Screen Shot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi6g1.png)

For some reason, the constraints make the content view be in the middle of the screen. Also, it scrolls in every direction. I want the content to be scrollable only in vertical direction like in `UITableView`. so that I can't move it like below:

[image: Screen Shot]

What am I doing wrong? I have checked all the tutorials and answers I can find in StackOverflow and Google, and no one actually has just a bizarre problem, so I am asking for help.

**EDIT:** I also added ContentView's width and height as constraints and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For disabling the horizontal scroll, you can set the content size in the (void)scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
```

You'll also want to set the directional lock so only 1 scroll direction is used at a time.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/directionalLockEnabled

```
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you! Horizontal scroll is disabled.

Comment: no prob.. as for the auto layout issue, are you using interface builder or using auto layout through code?

Comment: I am using the interface builder. I changed the constraint left and right to -16 and it worked. I don't believe its the correct behavior. Is there a way to make it work with 0?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with interface builder.  I typically use the constraintsWithVisualFormat method in code.  But, maybe try to remove the constraints for the contentView.  I normally set the contentView size in layoutSubviews for the subview(s) inside my scrollview.

Comment: self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * _pageCount, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);  This is how I've done it in the past, though I was paging through different views in the uiscrollview.

Answer (score 57):

You can do this entirely using constraints and it's really easy.

The `UIScrollView` just needs to understand how much width and space it has inside it.  So it needs to have something pinned to the `Leading`, `Trailing`, `Top` & `Bottom` constraints.  Also the width and height of the content needs to be fixed (this does not mean I have to specificy it.  I can still use constraints to achieve this.)

1. Add a `UIScrollView` and position as required.
2. Add a `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView` for the content.
3. Set the `Leading`, `Trailing`, `Top` & `Bottom` constraints of the content `UIView` to be 0.
4. Add an `Equal Width` constraint to the `UIScrollView` and `UIView`.  This will make it vertically scrolling only.
5. You now need to set the height of the content `UIView`.  You can then either specify the height of the content view (blech) or use the height of the controls contained within by making sure the bottom control is constrained to the bottom of the content view.

I did this and it worked a treat.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I had the contentView equal to the superview of the UIScrollView. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the equal width constraint was the one I needed.

Answer (score 8):

To summarize the Leszek S' answer:

In order to have a vertically scrolling view, **all the views inside the scroll view must have their** **width constraint** set. Easy to just set to the scroll view's superview.

The reason is that the scroll view will not scroll horizontally so as long as none of its subviews need to scroll horizontally. For example, if you have a label, set to 0 lines, auto layout will try to make the label as wide as it can before it starts adding lines and line breaks. If there are no explicit width constraints on the label it'll just make the scroll view content area wider. Constraints for trailing to the scroll view are ignored.

If you have a bunch of views, you might want to put them inside a single containing view like in that video. For my case, I only have 5 or 6 labels which can dynamically change height, but should never change width so I just made them all the same width as the scroll view. And bingo, vertically scrolling view with labels that grow or shrink depending on the text.

Answer (score 8):

Tested with Swift 4-5 in Xcode 12.1 Vertical Scroll View Setup

1. Add a Scroll View and set top, bottom, left and right constraints to 0.
   [image]
2. Remove the Scroll View "Content Layout Guides" by un selecting it in the Size inspector.[image]
3. Add uiview to Scroll View.
   [image]

4.We need to set the constraints of the uiview in relation to the scroll view. Control click the uiview and then attach to scroll view.

[image]

5. This brings up the constraints between the two.

[image]

6. Hold down shift to select more than one. We need to add Equal Widths, Equal Heights, Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom.

[image]

7. Edit Equal Height to: Superview priority to 250 from 1000.

[image]

8. Now add the content. For simplicity I added an image and a label with 0 lines in Attribute inspector and lots of text in view did load.

[image]

9. Final Result!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have written a function that allows to scroll content vertically but not horizontally. It creates a UIView with limited width inside scrollview and embeds all scrollview subviews in it.

```
TegScrolledContent.createContentView(scrollView)
```

https://github.com/exchangegroup/scrollable-content-ios

[image]

Comment: Thanks evegenii,your library really help me out at my Sign In View when go to landscape left and right..

Answer (score 2):

Along with @derek's answer I would like to add that setting contentOffset always in **scrollViewDidScroll** will cause performance issue . So please check only if x is not 0 then set contentOffset

```
    if(contentOffset.x != 0){
        setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, contentOffset.y), animated: false)
    }
```

and yes to the scrollview

```
directionalLockEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Give content view explicit height and width constraints

Comment: I did -> Width: 568, Height: 320. No luck

Comment: Maybe your content view is shrinker by its subviews. Are you getting auto layout exceptions?

Comment: Not, not a single one. Here is the thing. I started to play with the constraint values and putting -16 for both leading and tailing constraints actually fixed the view being in the middle... I really don't want to rely on a number like that. What can be the cause of this problem? What do you mean by shrinker? Moreover, now even though the scrollview works, it doesn't scroll to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a snippet that I have used to achieve a vertical-only scroll view.
It works by adding a content view as a child view of a scroll view, then constraining the width of that content view to the width of the parent scroll view. From then, all of the subviews should be added to the content view rather than to the scroll view.

```
// View that will contain content of scroll view. Width is constrained to the width of the scroll view.
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];

views[@"contentView"] = contentView;
[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

// Now, add all your subviews to contentView
```