# Can i redefine the (0,0) point in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scrollview with many items on it . i would like to scroll down to a point and save that point as my new (0,0) point (i.e. all other items attached to the scroll view will see that point as a (0,0) point . Can i do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use contentInset (see [What's the UIScrollView contentInset property for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983463)). Additionally, you might want to move the view that contains your other items within the UIScrollView to the new zero point (by setting its frame), but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

The contentOffset is relevant, too, if you need to scroll to that point programmatically.