# iOS8 UITextView cursor below frame when changing frame with Animation

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

I am trying to display the cursor above the keyboard **with some animation** also trying to scroll the UITextView background lines correctly.

I had solved this problem in iOS 7 perfercly using the code below but it broke on iOS 8, I think the reason is that I am trying to override **scrollRangeToVisible** in iOS8 but I am unable to do so, **its not called automatically like in iOS 7**. The keyboard is displayed the moment the UITextView is touched, so I don't have control over how to scroll things. my UITextView has lines as well.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView
{
    caretVisibilityTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(scrollCaretToVisible) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView
{
    [caretVisibilityTimer invalidate];

    caretVisibilityTimer = nil;
}

-(void) scrollRangeToVisible: (NSRange) range {
    printf("scrollRangeToVisible \n");
}

- (void) scrollCaretToVisible {
    printf("scrollCaretToVisible \n");

    //[self becomeFirstResponder];

    //This is where the cursor is at.
    CGRect caretRect = [self caretRectForPosition: self.selectedTextRange.end];

    if (CGRectEqualToRect(caretRect, oldRect))
        return;

    oldRect = caretRect;

    //This is the visible rect of the textview.
    CGRect visibleRect = self.bounds;

    visibleRect.size.height -= (self.contentInset.top + self.contentInset.bottom);

    visibleRect.origin.y = self.contentOffset.y;

    //We will scroll only if the caret falls outside of the visible rect.
    if (!CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, caretRect)) {
        CGPoint newOffset = self.contentOffset;

        newOffset.y = MAX((caretRect.origin.y + caretRect.size.height) - visibleRect.size.height, 0);

        //Added This section
        //=======================================
        // Calculates new contentOffset
        if (caretRect.origin.y < visibleRect.origin.y)
        // rect precedes bounds, scroll up
            newOffset.y = caretRect.origin.y - self.contentInset.top - self.bottomPadding;

        else
        // rect follows bounds, scroll down
            newOffset.y = caretRect.origin.y + self.contentInset.bottom + caretRect.size.height - self.bounds.size.height;
        //=======================================

        /* */
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ (void)
            //dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
            {
                [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
                [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
                [self setContentOffset: newOffset animated: YES];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            });

        //[self setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Refrence
[UITextView cursor below frame when changing frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431684/uitextview-cursor-below-frame-when-changing-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I have found that for iOS8 I needed to override scrollRectToVisible which is the equivalent of overriding scrollRangeToVisible in iOS7

iOS7

```
- (void) scrollRangeToVisible:(NSRange)range { }
```

iOS8

```
- (void) scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated{ [self scrollCaretToVisible]; }
```