# How to scroll to current cursor position in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift2

I've searched all over S.O. for a simple solution to get the cursor's current position, then scroll to it (assuming the keyboard ***is*** visible). Most seem overly complicated and/or ineffective in certain situations. How can I make scrolling work every time, whether the cursor is below a keyboard or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Be sure your `UITextView`'s `contentInset`s are properly set & your `textView` is already `firstResponder` before doing this. The `contentInset` property tells the `textView` where the visible area is for the user. If the keyboard is visible, be sure the `textView.contentInset.bottom` property has been set to the top border of the keyboard otherwise the `textView` may scroll to a space not visible, behind the keyboard.

See this S.O. post for more information: [What's the UIScrollView contentInset property for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983463/whats-the-uiscrollview-contentinset-property-for)

2) After my the insets are ready to go, and the `textView` is `firstResponder`, I call the following function:

```
private func scrollToCursorPositionIfBelowKeyboard() {
    let caret = textView.caretRectForPosition(textView.selectedTextRange!.start)
    let keyboardTopBorder = textView.bounds.size.height - keyboardHeight!

   // Remember, the y-scale starts in the upper-left hand corner at "0", then gets
   // larger as you go down the screen from top-to-bottom. Therefore, the caret.origin.y
   // being larger than keyboardTopBorder indicates that the caret sits below the
   // keyboardTopBorder, and the textView needs to scroll to the position.
   if caret.origin.y > keyboardTopBorder {
        textView.scrollRectToVisible(caret, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

**Optional**: If you just want to scroll to the cursor's current position (assuming the `textView` is currently `firstResponder` and `contentInset` has been properly set before now),  just call:

```
private func scrollToCursorPosition() {
    let caret = textView.caretRectForPosition(textView.selectedTextRange!.start)
    textView.scrollRectToVisible(caret, animated: true)
 }
```

**Extra Information:** In order to set the `textView` scroll bars to the proper height, modify the `scrollIndicatorInsets` by doing something like:

```
// This is not relative to the coordinate plane. You simply set the `.bottom` property 
// as if it were a normal height property. The textView does the rest for you.
textView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight 
textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = textView.contentInset // Matches textView's visible space.
```