# Main view taking top space from scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have made a ui in which i am showing some textfileds.I have added all textfields inside a mainview & added mainview under scrollview.But main view is always taking space from top.I have added

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in scroll view .But that make scroll view static. Then the scroll view does not scroll.I am changing the contentSize of scrollview on when keyboard appears & disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try :**

Select ViewContoller in storyboard check a property in attribute Inspector "Adjust Scroll View Insets" untick that,in my case it worked .

Comment: I want to know why it was having that top space.Now when it is uncheck then how it is working.Please tell for knowledge

Comment: This is a boolean value that decides that whether the view controller should automatically adjust its scroll view insets and defaults to YES

Comment: What s scrollview insects here.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983463/whats-the-uiscrollview-contentinset-property-for

Answer (score 1):

Check you have not set properly constrain to your content view.

You have set height and width equal to scrollview but you need to set it respected to your Mainview.

**Please set your constrain in this way. and Run your Viewcontroller again**

[image]

Comment: For me it is not working.I have not set the equal width & height constraints for maiview i have set it leading,trailing,yop,bottom constraints here.

Comment: Why i need to set equal height & width.I have set it center horizontal & vertical

Comment: I am still having the issue.Yop space from scroll view in uiview

Comment: can you show me your scrollview and view's constrain ?

Comment: Reshmi answer worked for me.Thank you for your guidance.But can u tell y u suggested like this

Comment: Good .I guess you have not set constrain correctly. when i am learning autolayout i faced same issue like you.

Answer (score -1):

Use this. This is very useful one.

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)