# show the keyboard of a textfield on top of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

In my iPhone apps, my problem is that I have a textfield at the bottom of the screen, so when the keyboard appear, he hides the textfied, there is a way to show the keyboard on the top of the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 4):

You should move your view when the keyboard appears.
The code is:

In .m file

```
- (void) loginViewUp : (UIView*) view
{   
    if(!alreadyViewUp)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect rect = view.frame;
        rect.origin.y -= View_Move_Hight;
        view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        alreadyViewUp = !alreadyViewUp;
    }
}

- (void) loginViewDown :(UIView*) view
{        
    if(alreadyViewUp)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect rect = view.frame;
        rect.origin.y += View_Move_Hight;
        view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        alreadyViewUp = !alreadyViewUp;
    }
}
```

In .h file

```
- (void) loginViewUp : (UIView*) view;
```

here

```
#define View_Move_Hight 170
```

is defined before `@implementation`.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You should design your view so that it shifts up with the keyboard, iPhone users are used to the keyboard always being on the bottom of the screen so this would go against the HIG