# Custom inputAccessoryView push my UITableView first row partially off the screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

For my scenario, I have a UITableView with a UITextField for the first row. While I try to set custom toolbar for keyboard with UITextField.inputAccessoryView, it pushed my first row of textfield partially off the screen. This is not happening if I avoid adding the toolbar. Refer screen shot below:

[image: Keyboard on screen; top row of table pushed up under the navigation bar]

I tried with NSNotification with keyboardWillShow by reposition to first row of the tableview, but it just look awkward for the table pulling out and in. It might be something to do overriding UITableView/UIScrollView, but I am out of idea how to do this.

Would like to know how you guys resolve this.

Thanks you!

Comment: How are you adding the tableView and toolbar? Through interface builder or programatically?

Comment: The toolbar is from interface builder, you can customize it with KeyboardAccessoryView. Just load the nib and set.

Answer (score 0):

This question might help: [iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field)