# Keyboard covers up my UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, objective-c-2.0

I have a UIViewController which has a UITextView and UIImageView, when the keyboard comes up it covers up my UITextView. so how can i do to manage that and the same for the UITableView?
[image: UIViewController]

[image: UITableViewController]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 2):

You can put all of the items inside a ScrollView and then move the view to compensate for the keyboard. Someone has already written a really handy class, check out: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Hope this helps!

Comment: ...and it works very well. You can find in http://iosdevblog.com/2014/07/26/keyboard-hides-text-fields/ a tutorial about it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good options for the first case:

1. Raise the `UITextView` programmatically when the keyboard is up and the `UITextView` is first responder following [this excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249023/544050) or [this equally excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1127025/544050).
2. Add everything onto a `UIScrollView` so that it moves appropriately when the keyboard is raised following [this simple tutorial](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-drop-in-universal-solution-for-moving-text-fields-out-of-the-way-of-the-keyboard/)

A `UITableView` will manage this pretty well for you automatically using the `– scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method, but either of the above solutions will also work.