# iphone: get position of a view

Tags: iphone, ios5, keyboard, position

I have a text field that is near the bottom of the screen. When the keyboard comes up, it covers the text field. I solved this problem by using the code in [iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field).

However, that code hardcodes how much views should move up or down. Is there a way that I can programmatically obtain the coordinates of my text field so that I can determine how much it needs to move up or down? This would be beneficial because I would not have to change the code if I ever decide to move this text field to a different location. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `frame` property on the UITextField (or any subclass of UIView).  The returned `CGRect`will provide access to `origin` which has either the x or y coordinate as a CGFloat.

```
CGFloat y = textField.frame.origin.y;
```

Comment: excellent, that worked! thank you. i'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: actually, I have a follow up question. why is CGFloat y = [[[textField frame] origin] y]; not working? I also tried with an * after the CGFloat. thanks!

Comment: The origin is a CGPoint which is a struct. Structs are accessed with the `.` operator. Objective-C methods and properties can be accessed with the brackets `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The distance of the text field from the bottom of the screen should be equal or greater than the height of the keyboard.

```
float distanceFromBottom = txtField.window.frame.size.height - txtField.frame.origin.y - txtField.frame.size.height;
float deltaY = keyboardHeight - distanceFromBottom;
```

You should move the text field up by `deltaY`.