# Fix keyboard with editable Text field 

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, screen

How can I fix the keyboard on view with editable Text field just as we see in in messaging?

[image]

I want to show exactly the same layout. I couldn't find how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

For creating such view you need to take a `UIToolBar` and add a `UITextField` and a `UIBarButtonItem` on it.
On touching `UITextField` or on pressing **return** key or **Send** button you need to animate your complete view as given in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field/1533847#1533847) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inputAccessoryView of UITextField to attach your toolBar above the keyboard

Comment: I have find out the way to this simply i have made my button by which this view will appear  to be the  first responder :) and done with it Thank you everyone for helping !