# Populate TableView Cell Inquiry

Tags: ios, uitextfield, toolbar

I have created a table view controller sort of a master-detail approach, when I click on the master view the detail view would come out with a textfield at the bottom of the screen contained within a view on a toolbar.

My question is how can I automatically adjust the position of the toolbar when the keyboard pops-out when I clicked on the textfield, currently when I enter on the textfield the keyboard comes out covering my textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the keyboard covers your textfield check this question and answers

[iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field)

If you have more than a textfield, consider using a scrollview and move up when the keyboard appears.

Comment: I should refine my search keyword next time.. Thanks.