# How to show keyboard upper side of UItextfield when we enter text, in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextfield` in which I am entering value. I don't want to scroll myself or adjust `keyboard` myself , I want `Keyboard` automatically adjust itself when I enter text in `UITextfield` and always show below the `textfield`.

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Comment: You tried animate the whole view up?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I have used. Basically, what we're going to do is animate the position of the view whenever a `UITextField` gets focus. To do this, we must make our `UIViewController` a delegate of our `UITextFields`

define a variable **`float animatedDistance`** in .h of the file

```
 @interface <ClassName>

    float animatedDistance;

 @end

 static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
 static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
 static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
 static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
 static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
     CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

     CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
     CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
     CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
     CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

     if (heightFraction < 0.0)
     {
         heightFraction = 0.0;
     }
     else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
     {
         heightFraction = 1.0;
     }

     UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
     if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
     {
         animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
     }
     else
     {
         animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
     }

     CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
     viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

     [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

     [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
 }
```

Now that the view has been 'pushed up' when a `UITextField` is selected, we want to make sure that we slide it back down when we're done:

```
 - (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
     viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

     [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

For more Visit [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html)

Comment: define float animatedDistance in .h

Comment: animatedDistance is the value wch will animate your view by the distance

Comment: Superb code sir. Thanks aloot... The code is working fine... Exact what I wanted. Thanks aloot sir...

Comment: Not a problem lemme know if nething else required

Answer (score 0):

Animate the frame (viewcontroller.view.frame.origin.y - 215) of your view that contains the textfield when the textfield starts editing and back down when it is finished.

Use the UITextfieldDelegate methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) class which will help you to do the needful. All you need to do is make the class of that UITableView to TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView. Same for UIScrollView and UICollectionView. You can used these classes to avoid the keyboard.

Hope this helps. And if it does, please accept. ;)
Thanks and Cheers.