# textFieldDidBeginEditing: not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got the code below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield) SO question. I'm trying to slide up textfields when I begin editing (because they otherwise get covered by the iPhone keyboard). However, the log statement reveals that the textFieldDidBeginEditing method is not getting called.

I have the code below in two different subclasses of UIViewController. In one of them, for example, I have a textfield connected from the storyboard to the UIViewController like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mnemonicField;
```

I moved the textfield up to the top of the view (i.e. not covered by keyboard) so that I could edit it to try to trigger the log statement but it didn't work. The text field otherwise works as expected i.e. the data I enter is getting saved to coreData etc etc.

Can you explain what I might be doing wrong?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"The did begin edit method was called");
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 180; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Does any of the other delegate methods are called or when did you set the delegate?

Comment: @larme I have to set a delegate for this to work? didn't know that

Comment: `textFieldDidEndEditing`: is a delegate method. It's a `UITextFieldDelegate` method, not a `UITextField` one.

Comment: For me I had added my TextField to a UIViewController and that UIViewController's view I had added as a subview to my main VC. I needed to then go to my main VC and include the code `[self addChildViewController:myVC];` for textField delegates to start working in that VC. Amazed I haven't encountered this before

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have not assigned your `delegate` of `UITextField` in your `ViewController` class:

In your viewcontroller.m file, In `ViewDidLoad` method, do this:

```
self.mnemonicField.delegate=self;
```

In your viewcontroller.h file, do this:

```
@interface YourViewController : ViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set up text field delegate to self.
Add this line to viewDidLoad method:

```
self.mnemonicField.delegate = self;
```

and remember to add this line `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to conform to that protocol.

You can achieve the same effect in storyboard by control drag from desired UITextField to view controller and select delegate.

Answer (score 4):

You created IBOutlet so just drag your textfield to viewController and set delegate

[image]  Then in .h add the following

```
@interface ViewController : ViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

In other case if you click any other button without moving the focus of Uitextfield then delegate will not be called, for that you need to explicitly call

```
yourtextfield.resignFirstResponder()
```