# Textfield doesn't respond to textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a view which implements UIViewController. This ViewController implements UITextFieldDelegate. On my view I have three textfields. All three fields are outlets set to my ViewController.

When I implement textFieldDidBeginEditing no event fires for any of my three textfields. Is there something obvious Im missing?

I got to my current scene after selecting a record in a tableview from a previous scene. When select the record in the tableView, I use prepareForSegue to get the selected record and pass its corresponding model to my ViewController in question. This is the last place where I can manipulate those textfields.

Comment: did you set the delegate for the text fields?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks Kex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [textFieldDidBeginEditing: not getting called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611104/textfielddidbeginediting-not-getting-called)