# TextField not showing on a view that has table on top and textfield at bottom

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have a view with a table on top and textfield at the bottom. Kind of like chat. I envision that when the user types something in the `TextField` and presses send button (not shown in screenshot) the table will update with that entry.

[image]

**Question**

My problem is that when I click into the `TextField`, the keyboard shows up but the `TextField` isn't visible. As shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

This is how I'm making the two views:

```
@my_table = rmq(self.view).append(UITableView, :top_style).get
@bottom = rmq(self.view).append(UIView, :bottom_style).get
@bottom = rmq(:bottom_style)
@send = @bottom.append(UITextField, :send).get
```

**Stylesheet**

```
  def top_style(st)
    st.frame = {t: 0, l: 0, w: screen_width, h: screen_height - 100}
    st.background_color = color.white
  end

  def bottom_style(st)
    st.frame = {t: screen_height-100, l: 0, w: screen_width, h: screen_height}
    st.background_color = color.battleship_gray
  end

  def send(st)
    st.frame = {l: 3, t: 5, w: 220, h: 30}
    st.background_color = color.white
    st.view.font = font.small
    st.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    st.view.placeholder = "say something..."
  end
```

**update**

output from RMQ log

```
─── UIView  282653120  {l: 0, t: 64, w: 320, h: 504}
    ├─── UITableView  ( top_style )  264785408  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 468}
    │    ├─── UITableViewWrapperView  282624240  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 468}
    │    │    ├─── NotesCell  ( note_cell )  282682640  {l: 0, t: 60, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellScrollV  282585904  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellContent  282688128  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    │    ├─── UILabel  ( cell_label )  282583168  {l: 15, t: 0, w: 290, h: 30}
    │    │    ├─── NotesCell  ( note_cell )  282696944  {l: 0, t: 30, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellScrollV  282690432  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellContent  282617184  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    │    ├─── UILabel  ( cell_label )  282578944  {l: 15, t: 0, w: 290, h: 30}
    │    │    ├─── NotesCell  ( note_cell )  282671168  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellScrollV  282723568  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    ├─── UITableViewCellContent  282709936  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 320, h: 30}
    │    │    │    │    │    ├─── UILabel  ( cell_label )  282653440  {l: 15, t: 0, w: 290, h: 30}
    │    ├─── UIImageView  282715328  {l: 316.5, t: 461, w: 3.5, h: 7}
    │    ├─── UIImageView  282714752  {l: 313, t: 464.5, w: 7, h: 3.5}
    ├─── UIView  ( bottom_style )  282440352  {l: 0, t: 468, w: 320, h: 568}
    │    ├─── UITextField  ( send )  282618928  {l: 3, t: 5, w: 220, h: 30}
    │    │    ├─── UITextFieldLabel  282587568  {l: 0, t: 0, w: 220, h: 29}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you creating the views? Inside a custom `UITableViewCell`? If so, in your `layoutSubviews` method, make sure not to call `super` and the system titleview and subtlte view won't be created.

See here for an example: https://github.com/MohawkApps/aloft/blob/master/app/views/wind_cell.rb#L18

EDIT... didn't quite understand the question previously.

Looks like you're going to have to manually reposition the bottom view when the keyboard is shown and hidden. Try something like this:

```
def create_stuff
  @my_table = rmq(self.view).append(UITableView, :top_style).get
  @bottom = rmq(self.view).append(UIView, :bottom_style).get
  @bottom = rmq(:bottom_style)
  @send = @bottom.append(UITextField, :send).get
  @send.get.delegate = self # This is crucial for the rest to work
end

def textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField)
  rmq(@bottom).animate(
    duration: 0.3,
    animations: lambda{|q|
      q.move top: keyboard_height # Animate it somewhere
    }
  )
end

def textFieldDidEndEditing(textField)
  rmq(@bottom).animate(
    duration: 0.3,
    animations: lambda{|q|
      q.move top: -keyboard_height # Animate it somewhere
    }
  )
end
```

Something along those lines should work.

Comment: both the views (table view and uiview) are being created in a separate UIView. So they are both under an umbrella `UIView`. I've updated the question with output of `rmq.log :tree`. I will look at the example you posted. Thanks

Comment: I also came across this but not sure if that'll solve my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield