# Keep IQKeyboardManager from removing my Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

This is a follow up to [iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield/17707094#17707094), which talks about keeping the keyboard from covering the text fields. The answer that works for me is the one about using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). The problem for me is that it dismisses my navigation bar. The document says

> If you don't want to hide the default UINavigationBar of
>   UINavigationController when keyboardManager slides up the view, then
>   just change the UIView class to UIScrollView from the storyboard or
>   xib.

But I am not sure which UIView it is talking about. Since the SO thread that mentions this has hundreds of up-votes, I imaging someone have had to deal with this. Will someone please share how they might have done this? (also I am very new to iOS, so please no esoteric talks).

Answer (score 2):

In order to not hide your `UINavigationBar` of `UINavigationController` you need to set the `self.view` class from `UIView` to `UIScrollView`. That's all the documentation says.

I've updated the documentation [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) with screenshot which can be very helpful to follow the steps.