# Keyboard covers textfield in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am implementing the JSQMessagesViewController library for messaging. I have small issue with the keyboard, when the textfield ist edited, the keyboard covers the textfield, and i should slide it down to see what did i write. 
They have a class JSQMessagesKeyboardController which is handling the keyboard..

I tried this solution from here: [iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield) but nothing changed.

Does someone had the same problem, would you share possible solutions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

override

```
 func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {   
   keyboardController.beginListeningForKeyboard()
 }
```